# Create a text document in python with whats in the variable as the name

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, text-files

I am trying to create a questionnaire in python using tkinter. so far I can:

1) use radio buttons, check boxes, spin box and entry form.

2) display these results in the text box using variables for each answer:

```
textbox.delete(0.0, END)
textbox.insert(END, name)
textbox.insert(END, "\n")
textbox.insert(END, "Age: ")
```

and so on...

what I need to do is save these to a text document. Because it is a Questionnaire I want to save the file individually, so by the name of the person completing it. Unfortunately it wont allow me to open a word file while using a variable. (the variable I am using is called "name")

The error that appears is:

---

```
File "D:\Questionaire\module1.py", line 72, in button

newfile = open(name)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'James'
```

(James was the word in the variable at the time)

---

```
newfile = open(name)
newfile.write("line one\n")
newfile.write("line two\n")
```

Is there a way to create a text file with a variable, so each time the word file created doesn't replace the one created before?

I have tried explaining as best I could, as any questions if it doesn't make sense.

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function incorrectly, to write to a file, you need to open it with the `"w"` write mode.

Try using

```
newfile = open(name, "w")
newfile.write("line one\n")
newfile.write("line two\n")
newfile.close()
```

or better still

```
with open(name, "w") as name_file:
    name_file.write("line one\n")
    name_file.write("line two\n")
```

However, it is quite possible for two people to have the same name, and so, the values will get overwritten if we open the file in write mode everytime. So, the right choice will be to open the file in `append` mode:

```
with open(name, "a") as name_file:
    name_file.write("line one\n")
    name_file.write("line two\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! That has worked perfectly! I will tick in 11 minuets.